# I want to make all the updates in pl sql without using update statement with the help of cursor for loop

Tags: sql

I have create a big table named accounting_book I store data here from another table named Revenue
and now I want to update those records without using update statement with the help of cursor for loop in oracle database.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

DECLARE
 CURSOR SKC IS
 SELECT TXNSEQ,TXNID,CASHAMT,CHECKAMT, PPAMT,CARDAMT
 FROM REVENUE;

 BEGIN
 FOR a_REVENUE IN SKC LOOP
     INSERT INTO ACCOUNTING_BOOK(TXNSEQ,TXNID,CASHAMT,
     CHECKAMT,PPAMT,CARDAMT)
        VALUES(a_REVENUE.TXNSEQ, a_REVENUE.TXNID, a_REVENUE.CASHAMT, a_REVENUE.CHECKAMT, a_REVENUE.PPAMT, a_REVENUE.CARDAMT);

 END LOOP;

 COMMIT;

 END;
 /
```

What should I do next please give me some suggetion...

Comment: Why do you want to update records without using an update command ? Even for-loop uses UPDATE comand to perform an update, this is the easiest way. I can imagine that you can do DELETE then INSERT to reinsert updated row again, but I don't get why do you want to do it this way, it's strange.

Comment: That's what my project demands.

Comment: Looks like you forgot to open an then close cursor, but still where are you getting problem??

Comment: I want to use case statement in the time of inserting data into table.That's my code: